# Missing items from synchronized HashMap in a threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading

I know you have to synchronize around anything that would change the structure of a hashmap (put or remove) but it seems to me you also have to synchronize around reads of the hashmap otherwise you might be reading while another thread is changing the structure of the hashmap.

So I sync around gets and puts to my hashmap.
The only machines I have available to me to test with all only have one processor so I never had any real concurrency until the system went to production and started failing. Items were missing out of my hashmap. I assume this is because two threads were writing at the same time, but based on the code below, this should not be possible. When I turned down the number of threads to 1 it started working flawlessly, so it's definitely a threading problem.

Details:

```
// something for all the threads to sync on
private static Object EMREPORTONE = new Object();


    synchronized (EMREPORTONE)
      {
        reportdatacache.put("name.." + eri.recip_map_id, eri.name);
        reportdatacache.put("subjec" + eri.recip_map_id, eri.subject);
        etc...
      }
```

... and elsewhere....

```
    synchronized (EMREPORTONE)
      {
        eri.name = (String)reportdatacache.get("name.." + eri.recip_map_id);
        eri.subject = (String)reportdatacache.get("subjec" + eri.recip_map_id);
        etc...
      }
```

and that's it. I pass around reportdatacache between functions, but that's just the reference to the hashmap.

Another important point is that this is running as a servlet in an appserver (iplanet to be specific, but I know none of you have ever heard of that)

But regardless, EMREPORTONE is global to the webserver process, no two threads should be able to step on each other, yet my hashmap is getting wrecked. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried just using `Collections.synchronizedMap`?  Or even a `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that all accesses to the `HashMap` are `synchronized`?  Any `for` loops, iterators, ...?

Comment: I would recommend synchronizing on the `reportdatacache` object itself instead of using a static `EMREPORTONE`.

Comment: Stupid question but there definitely is _one_ `EMREPORTONE` field right?  It is `private static` so both the puts and the gets are in the same file?

Comment: concurrenthashmap is only available in 6 I'm running 5. Don't ask. All accessess to the hashmap are synced on the same static Object, but I will change it to sync on the hashmap itself. I'm also changing it to use synchronized map, but not sure that explains where the failure is.

Comment: yes, all puts and gets are in that one class. That one class implements Runnable so all the threading goes on in there only.

Comment: only because you called me dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In servlet container environment static variables depend on classloader. So you may think that you're dealing with same static instance, but in fact it could be completely different one.

Additionally, check if you do not use the map by escaped reference elsewhere and write/remove keys from it.

And yes, use ConcurrentHashMap instead.

Comment: If he was dealing with a different classloader then he would be dealing with a different `reportdatacache` as well and there would not be any race conditions.

Comment: That's what I thought too. And also, we all assume concurrenthashmap is easily available, right? Yeah, well where I live, we only have java 1.5 so I don't have that yet. But I'll try syncing around the object itself. Makes more sense that way anyway.

Comment: @stu according to specs, ConcurrentHashMap appeared in Java 5

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

so what is the problem?

Comment: @Gray it's not about reportdatacache, but about synchronization on EMREPORTONE.

Comment: I understand.  I'm just saying that if we are talking about 2 classloaders for `EMREPORTONE` then we would be talking about 2 classloaders for `reportdatacache` as well.

Comment: @Gray sometimes it's not true - depends on JVM optimizations. But anyway I believe that the problem of topic starter is outside this stuff. Quote "I pass around reportdatacache between functions, but that's just the reference to the hashmap." - so if he does not synch on his lock when getting item from hashmap - ordering is undefined and memory barrier is not broken. And this is real root of evil IMHO :)

Comment: He is not able to pass around anything between classloaders @jdevelop.      JVM optimizations would not impact that basic fact.  But I agree that the problem lies elsewhere.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, synchronization is not only important when writing, but also when reading. While a write will be performed under mutually exclusion, a reader might access an errenous state of the map.

I **cannot recommend** you under any circumstances to **synchronize** the Java Collections **manually**, there are thread-safe counterparts: [Collections.synchronizedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) and [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). Use them, they will ensure, that access to them is safe in a multithreaded environment.

Futher hints, it seems that everyone is accesing the `datareportcache`. Is there only one instance of that object? Why not synchronize then on the cache itself? But forget then when trying to solve your problems, use the sugar from **java.util.concurrent**.

Comment: I will make it a synchronized map, but you still have to lock around access to it, which is fine, no worse than what I'm doing now, but I'm not sure it explains why it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it there are 3 possibilities here:

1. You are locking on two different objects.   `EMREPORTONE` is `private static` however and the code that accesses the `reportdatacache` is in one file only.  Ok, that isn't it then.  But I would recommend locking on `reportdatacache` instead of `EMREPORTONE` however.  Cleaner code.
2. You are missing some read or write to `reportdatacache` somewhere.  There are other accesses to the map that are not `synchronized`.  Are things never removed from the cache?
3. This isn't a synchronization problem but rather a race condition issue.  The data in the hashmap is fine but you are expecting things to be in the cache but they haven't be stored by the other thread yet.   Maybe 2 requests come in for the same `eri` at the same time and they are both putting values into the cache?  Maybe check to see if the old value returned by `put(...)` is always null?  Maybe explaining more about how you know that items are missing from the map would help with this.

As an aside, you are doing this:

```
reportdatacache.put("name.." + eri.recip_map_id, eri.name);
reportdatacache.put("subjec" + eri.recip_map_id, eri.subject);
```

But it seems like you really should be storing the `eri` by its id.

```
reportdatacache.put(recip_map_id, eri);
```

Then you aren't creating fake keys with the `"name.."` prefix.  Or maybe you should create a `NameSubject` `private static class` to store the name and subject in the cache.  Cleaner.

Hope something here helps.

Comment: the ugly hash contents are so I can serialize the hash easily, so all keys are unique strings and all the values are simple types, not eris which aren't easily serializable.

Comment: I changed the lock to the hashmap itself. awaiting the next release schedule. Nothing is ever removed from the cache, it is blown away and rebuilt from scratch when it gets stale.

Comment: Why do you care about serialized?  Is this saved to a file and read in or something?